# grouping data in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame, this is a daily data. For every day, I have free space for each file system. I like to graph this. I was thinking to put each file system on its own column to create R graphs. How can I go about doing this. Without moving them to their own columns, can I create a chart for each file system for each day?

```
     Date     fileSystem FreeSpace
2011-12-03     /var          99.785
2011-12-03     /opt          30.494
2011-12-03     /tmp          55.643
2011-12-03     /data         37.846
2011-12-03     /ora          0.578
2011-12-04     /var          99.785
2011-12-04     /opt          30.494
2011-12-04     /tmp          55.643
2011-12-04    /data         37.846
2011-12-04     /ora          0.578
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities for this in R... Something like this? 
However if you want to plot for each file system *and* each day, there would be only one bar (don`t if this is much usefull...).

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Date     fileSystem FreeSpace
                 2011-12-03     /var          99.785
                 2011-12-03     /opt          30.494
                 2011-12-03     /tmp          55.643
                 2011-12-03     /data         37.846
                 2011-12-03     /ora          0.578
                 2011-12-04     /var          99.785
                 2011-12-04     /opt          30.494
                 2011-12-04     /tmp          55.643
                 2011-12-04    /data         37.846
                 2011-12-04     /ora          0.578
                 ")

## using ggplot (dates are faceted)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = fileSystem, y = FreeSpace)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~Date)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
or as a line chart. Nearly everything is possible in R, but you must think about what kind of plot you want...

```
df$Date <- strptime(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = FreeSpace)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~fileSystem)
```

[image]

**Edit2:**
Perhabs this? Here I make a plot for every filesystem with a for-loop. The plots are stored in a list.

```
# or as a line chart
df$Date <- strptime(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
plotlist <- vector(mode="list", length(levels(df$fileSystem)))
for(i in levels(df$fileSystem)){
  tempdf <- df[df$fileSystem == i, ]
  plotlist[[i]] <- ggplot(tempdf, aes(x = Date, y = FreeSpace)) +
    geom_line() +
    opts(title = i)
}
plotlist[["/data"]]
plotlist[["/var"]]
```

Comment: this is a nice approach, but I need to see one graph for each file system for all the available dates.

Comment: I really appreciate this. I am getting this error: Error in if (length(range) == 1 || diff(range) == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
I like to put each file system on its' own column to to be able to graph seperate graphs that way. I may not want to look at every graph for certain ones.

Comment: Your error may be due to your data frame not being in the same format. Is the `Date` column of class `character` or `Date`? `str(df)` would show the difference, and that matters for the different types of graphs.

Comment: See, my edits. The code works for the example-data you have provided. If you get an error, than your example-data does not represent your real data.

Comment: I was able to fix the error by converting the date to POSIXct, but I like to convert this data frame to wide and be able to graph each column(file system). If I do it as above, not able to see the graphs.

Comment: If you want your data in wide format, you could use the reshape2 package:  require(reshape2);
dcast(df, Date~fileSystem)

Comment: @EDi, I really like your loop to store them in a list. One more question. How can I print all the items in the list. I like to see all the individual graphs showing up on the screen. Thank you very much, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

With lattice::xyplot you have many options:

```
require(lattice)
xyplot(FreeSpace ~ Date + fileSystem, data=df1)
xyplot(FreeSpace ~ Date | fileSystem, data=df1)
xyplot(FreeSpace ~ Date , group= fileSystem, data=df1)
xyplot(FreeSpace ~ Date , group= fileSystem, data=df1, type="b")
```

The lattice equivalent of the base `barplot` is `barchart`:

```
barchart(FreeSpace ~ Date | fileSystem, data=df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is hard to read in in that format; here is a reproducible version:

```
DF <-
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15311, 15311, 15311, 15311, 
15311, 15312, 15312, 15312, 15312, 15312), class = "Date"), fileSystem = structure(c(5L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("/data", "/opt", 
"/ora", "/tmp", "/var"), class = "factor"), FreeSpace = c(99.785, 
30.494, 55.643, 37.846, 0.578, 99.785, 30.494, 55.643, 37.846, 
0.578)), .Names = c("Date", "fileSystem", "FreeSpace"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'll also show examples with `ggplot2`:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
```

This uses grid faceting rather than wrapping like in @EDi's answer. One is not more right than the other; it depends on what you want.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=Date, y=FreeSpace)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("1 day")) +
  facet_grid(fileSystem~.)
```

[image]

Your other question was how to reshape the data.

```
library("reshape2")

DF.wide <- dcast(DF, Date~fileSystem, value.var="FreeSpace")
```

which gives

```
> DF.wide
        Date  /data   /opt  /ora   /tmp   /var
1 2011-12-03 37.846 30.494 0.578 55.643 99.785
2 2011-12-04 37.846 30.494 0.578 55.643 99.785
```

Individual columns can be plotted as desired, then.